# How I can pass settimeout function inside of if condition in node js api?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sendinblue

> I am working on mail sending api using node js and sendinblue, here i
> wrote my api inside of if condition is satisfied after 1 day only mail
> should send to user how i can pass here settimeout function here.
> and can u give some suggestion after 1 day one mail should send and
> after second day another mail should send automatically if user not
> clicked confirmation link. if any idea that one also can give how can
> i implement here.

```
const loginemail = async (req: Request) => {
    const connection = await createConnection()
    try {
        const [dashboardJobCount]: any = await connection.query(`select account_id,datediff(now(),created_date) as days,username,verified from account where verified=false;`)
      
        const client = Sib.ApiClient.instance
        
        const apiKey = client.authentications['api-key']
        apiKey.apiKey = process.env.SIB_API_KEY

        const tranEmailApi = new Sib.TransactionalEmailsApi()
      
        const sender = {
            email: 'jagadeeshwaran907@gmail.com',
            name: 'Anjan',
        }
        const receivers = [
            {
                email: 'jagadees979797@gmail.com',
            },
        ]
        const firstMail = {
            sender,
            to: receivers,
            subject: 'Testing mail 1st day',
            textContent: `
        Cules Coding will teach you how to become {{params.role}} a developer.
        `,
        templateId: 1,
       
            params: {
                role: 'Frontend',
            },
        }
        const secondMail = {
            sender,
            to: receivers,
            subject: 'Testing mail 2nd day',
            textContent: `
        Cules Coding will teach you how to become {{params.role}} a developer.
        `,
        templateId: 2,
       
            params: {
                role: 'Frontend',
            },
        }
        const thirdMail = {
            sender,
            to: receivers,
            subject: 'Testing mail 4th day',
            textContent: `
        Cules Coding will teach you how to become {{params.role}} a developer.
        `,
        templateId: 2,
       
            params: {
                role: 'Frontend',
            },
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < dashboardJobCount.length; i++) {
            if([1,93].includes(dashboardJobCount[i].days)){
          
             const msg = await tranEmailApi.sendTransacEmail(firstMail)
             return msg
            }
            else if([4,2,94].includes(dashboardJobCount[i].days)){
                const msg = await tranEmailApi.sendTransacEmail(secondMail)
                console.log("kkkk", dashboardJobCount[i].days)
                return msg
            }
            else if([6].includes(dashboardJobCount[i].days)){
                const msg = await tranEmailApi.sendTransacEmail(secondMail)
                console.log("kkkk", dashboardJobCount[i].days)
                return msg
            }
            else{
                console.log("your account has deleted")
            }
            
         }
        
       
    } catch (error) {
        await connection.end()
        throw error
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what are the different cases in which you need to send `firstMail`, `secondMail`, and `thirdMail`?

Comment: i am using the sendinblue template through firstmail will pass first template which i created in sendinblue second and third is different template. if i register today first template mail should pass in register mail is there one confirmation link if user not clicked that link mail should send second day please confirm like that mail we need to send in send mail

Comment: You need to send `firstMail` to users registered today that didn't click the confirmation link. `secondMail` to users registered yesterday that didn't click the confirmation link. Correct?

Comment: yes, correct...

Comment: I saw one blog they are suggested node schedule how should i implement here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just return a flag to indicate if the user has created the account today or yesterday and send the correct email based on that:

```
const loginemail = async (req: Request) => {
  const connection = await createConnection();
  try {
    const [dashboardJobCount]: any = await connection.query(`
    select 
        account_id, 
        IF (DATE(created_date) = CURDATE(), TRUE, FALSE) AS created_today
        username, 
        verified 
    from 
        account 
    where 
        verified=false
        AND DATE(created_date) = CURDATE()
        OR DATE(created_date) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    `);

    const client = Sib.ApiClient.instance;

    const apiKey = client.authentications['api-key'];
    apiKey.apiKey = process.env.SIB_API_KEY;

    const tranEmailApi = new Sib.TransactionalEmailsApi();

    const sender = {
      email: 'jagadeeshwaran907@gmail.com',
      name: 'Anjan',
    };
    const receivers = [
      {
        email: 'jagadees979797@gmail.com',
      },
    ];
    const firstMail = {
      sender,
      to: receivers,
      subject: 'Testing mail 1st day',
      textContent: `
        Cules Coding will teach you how to become {{params.role}} a developer.
        `,
      templateId: 1,

      params: {
        role: 'Frontend',
      },
    };
    const secondMail = {
      sender,
      to: receivers,
      subject: 'Testing mail 2nd day',
      textContent: `
        Cules Coding will teach you how to become {{params.role}} a developer.
        `,
      templateId: 2,

      params: {
        role: 'Frontend',
      },
    };
    const thirdMail = {
      sender,
      to: receivers,
      subject: 'Testing mail 4th day',
      textContent: `
        Cules Coding will teach you how to become {{params.role}} a developer.
        `,
      templateId: 2,

      params: {
        role: 'Frontend',
      },
    };
    for (let i = 0; i < dashboardJobCount.length; i++) {
      const mailToSend = dashboardJobCount[i].created_today
        ? firstMail
        : secondMail;
      await tranEmailApi.sendTransacEmail(mailToSend);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    await connection.end();
    throw error;
  }
};
```

Comment: Really thanks for this, if it is 3rd day how can i pass third mail i need to mail send for third day also.

Comment: if I register today i will get first mail ,in this mail i have one confirmation link if i am not click i need to send one reminder mail to 2 nd day and 3rd day please confirm like that it should wait for one day after that automatically mail should send for remainder, that is i am asking.

Comment: @jagab If you need to track if an e-mail as already been sent to a user on a specific day (if you need to call this function multiple times a day) you should log that and filter the users that already received an e-mail as well.